# AMD Ryzen 5950X slow with MKL 2020.0 and MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5

Tags: python, numpy, intel-mkl, amd-processor

I just bought a PC with Ryzen 5950x, it runs very fast on Matlab 2020b, by checking the result of `bench` command.

I followed the suggestions online by setting `MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5` globally, with **MKL 2020.0**. I have python 3.8.5 installed via anaconda, with numpy 1.20.0

When I try numpy with the following code with 5950x, it took **28 seconds** on average. I have another PC with intel i7-8700, it only needs **0.66 seconds**.

Can somebody tell me why? Or I should install BLAS instead of MKL?

```
import numpy as np
import os
from time import time

print(os.environ.get('MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE')) # it should print 5
# Let's take the randomness out of random numbers (for reproducibility)
np.random.seed(0)

size = 4096
A, B = np.random.random((size, size)), np.random.random((size, size))
C, D = np.random.random((size * 128,)), np.random.random((size * 128,))
E = np.random.random((int(size / 2), int(size / 4)))
F = np.random.random((int(size / 2), int(size / 2)))
F = np.dot(F, F.T)
G = np.random.random((int(size / 2), int(size / 2)))

N = 5
t = time()
for i in range(N):
    np.dot(A, B)
delta = time() - t
print('Dotted two %dx%d matrices in %0.2f s.' % (size, size, delta / N))
```

Comment: Why are you forcing the detection?  What do you get when you let MKL autodetect?

Comment: The results are the same. The detection does not change anything.

Comment: Somehow, after I reinstall anaconda, the problem is resolved. The product of two 4096x4096 matrix only took 0.4 seconds now.

Comment: Note that the MKL is mainly optimized for Intel CPUs as it is developed by Intel engineers. You can try to use BLIS which is open-source/free and recommended by AMD.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of it. If I install BLAS, then I have adjust other packages. I am happy with the current performance after reinstalling anaconda.

Comment: Hi there. I was wondering, I been considering the an 5950x but have been worried about linear algebra performance. Could you possibly try and run this script https://markus-beuckelmann.de/blog/boosting-numpy-blas.html and post your results here?

Answer (score 2):

Please install intel-oneapi-mkl-2021. Support for ryzen is embedded inside. You do not have to write `MKL_DEBUG_...`.

You can follow the link  : [intel-oneapi](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/installation-guide-for-intel-oneapi-toolkits-linux/top/installation/install-using-package-managers/yum-dnf-zypper.html)

Comment: Can you please make your  answer more clear by adding the difference between "stock" MKL and the oneapi thing you mentioned? What exactly is oneapi? What is the proof that this solution actually improves performance? Benchamrks?

Comment: @Astro intel-oneapi is the umbrella project for good old mkl. So if you want to use mkl you just install intel-oneapi.